# Limiting mapkit region on iPad

Tags: ipad, mapkit

I need to have an iPad app show a given country with some anotations using mapkit. Is it possible to limit it so the user can not scroll over to another region than the one i want to show?
For example, my app wants to show stuff about Brazil, can i make it so the user can not move away from that country?

This question is regarding Mapkit, i know i could have  an image of the country at question and try to get a similar effect to google map's...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work as I have never tried it, but I think it might.

Start by subclassing the MKMapView. Then, override all the touch handlers (e.g. touchesBegan:withEvent:, touchesEnded:withEvent:, etc...). In the overridden touch handlers do a bounds check on the current region being displayed on the mapview. If it is at (or maybe really close) to the edge of the area you want to show, then don't do anything with the touch event. Otherwise, just pass the touch event to the super classes implementation of the method.

If this works, let me know.